# 7zip commandline extract excluding single file with spaces in the file name

Tags: extract, 7zip

Using 7z.exe (v19.00 x64) from the commandline on Windows 11

I've tried these syntaxes:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" x -bb3 -x"Www.WebAddress.Net - My Website.url" -o_Extracted -psomething "ZippedFile (pwd something).zip"
```

Yields error:

> Incorrect wildcard type marker

---

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" x -bb3 -xWww.WebAddress.Net - My Website.url -psomething -o_Extracted "ZippedFile (pwd something).zip"
```

Yields error:

> Unknown switch

---

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" x -bb3 -x@exclude-list -psomething -o_Extracted "ZippedFile (pwd something).zip"
```

Contents of exclude-list:

> Www.WebAddress.Net - My Website.url
> Www.WebAddress.Net - My Website.*
> Www.WebAddress.Net - My Website
> *.url

This works but **DOES NOT** exclude the file *Www.WebAddress.Net - My Website.url* from extraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude a single file, as per the example:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" x -bb3 -x!"Www.WebAddress.Net - My Website.url" -psomething -o_Extracted "ZippedFile (pwd something).zip"
```

Use the **-x** switch and enclose the filename withing double-quotes.

To exclude a single file recursively:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" x -bb3 -xr!"Www.WebAddress.Net - My Website.url" -psomething -o_Extracted "ZippedFile (pwd something).zip"
```

To exclude all *.url* files recursively:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" x -bb3 -xr!*.url -psomething -o_Extracted "ZippedFile (pwd something).zip"
```

To exclude the list of files contained within the text file -x@**exclude-list** :

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" x -bb3 -x@exclude-list -psomething -o_Extracted "ZippedFile (pwd something).zip"
```